# How can I roll back a fix pack upgrade on Windows?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11.5

I have installed fix pack 11.5.8 for DB2 version 11.5 in Windows server 2016. Now this fix pack is not compatible with application. I have to downgrade to 11.5.7. How to roll back the fix pack (11.5.8) in windows server?

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstalling mod packs and fix packs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=products-uninstalling-mod-packs-fix-packs).

Install another db2 copy at 11.5.7 into different directory and run the `db2iupdt -f level /u:username,password DB2INSTNAME` from this copy.